# How do I make full page sized Bootstrap div?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I need to make a full-page sized div background.

So I'm having these two columns: col-9 sized div in gray and col-3 div in blue color. Here's the code of the two cols:

```css
@media print {
  @page {
    size: auto;
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test Full Page</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-9 h-100" style="background-color:#F8F8FF;">
        <div style="margin-top: 20px;">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-11">
              <br />
              <h4>Title</h4>
              <hr>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row" style="padding-left: 1.5rem;">
            <div class="col-6">
              <strong>Title</strong>
              <p align="justify">
                <span>Date</span>
              </p>
              <p align="justify">
                Blablabla
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 h-100" style="background-color:#0BA9FE;">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

How do I make both div cols full-sized height on every page? like the first page, second and third page. These two divs won't fill the entire page even when I added the `h-100` class.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: The `h-100` class applies `height: 100%!important;`, and a height in percent only works, if the parent element also has an explicit height. Use your own class, and apply `100vh` via that instead.

Comment: Scratch that last part, BS already has a class for that - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/sizing/#relative-to-the-viewport

Answer (score 0):

Remove **h-100** from the class in div.
Refer working code https://jsfiddle.net/pallaviyadav/n3Lus0v7/8/

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test Full Page</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-9" style="background-color:#F8F8FF;">
        <div style="margin-top: 20px;">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-11">
              <br />
              <h4>Title</h4>
              <hr>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row" style="padding-left: 1.5rem;">
            <div class="col-6">
              <strong>Title</strong>
              <p align="justify">
                <span>Date</span>
              </p>
              <p align="justify">
                Blablabla
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3" style="background-color:red;">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```